System of quadratic inequations
I have variables $x_1,...,x_n>0$, and fixed parameters $a_1,a_2,...a_n >0$.
I compute quantities $s_1,s_2,...,s_n$, each with one of the following types of equation:

$s_i =a_i(x_i - x_j x_k)$
$s_i =a_i(x_i - x_j)$
$s_i =a_i((x_i)^2 - x_j)$

where $j,k$ are different from $i$, but $j$ can be equal to $k$.
The inequalities to be satisfied are of the following form, for each $i$:
$$(\sum_{\text{$x_i$ appears negatively in $s_j$}}s_j) > s_i$$
where $s_j$ (resp. $s_i$) is replaced with $2s_j$ (resp. $2s_i$) if $x_i^2$ appears in it.
All quantities $x_i,s_i$ must be strictly positive, as are the $a_i$'s.
I assume that

the system is connected: if I create a graph with an edge $i\to j$ (and $i\to k$ if applicable) for each equation, then I obtain a strongly connected graph.

the wanted inequalities are consistent: they have a solution if considered in isolation.


Question: does there always exist a choice for $x_1,\dots x_n$ satisfying all inequalities?
Example and its solution, taking all $a_i$ equal to $1$:

$s_1 = ((x_1)^2 − x_2)$
$s_2 = (x_2  − x_3)$
$s_3 = (x_3 − x_1 x_2)$

giving inequalities $s_1 + s_3 > s_2 > s_3 > 2s_1 > 0$, which indeed have a solution in themselves ($s_1=2, s_3=5, s_2=6$). An example of solution for the $x_i$'s is then $x_1=0.5$, $x_2=0.234375$, $x_3=0.171875$.
It seems that there are enough degrees of freedom to always find a solution, but apart from working out specific examples I couldn't come up with a general argument.
EDIT
Here is an argument that seems to be generalisable. It treats the above example, even in presence of arbitrary $a_i$'s.
Let $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ be a solution to the inequalities. Since the inequalities are linear, any $(\lambda v_1, \lambda v_2, \lambda v_3)$ is also solution. Let $w_i=\frac{v_i}{a_i}$, we aim to find some $\lambda,x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $\frac{s_i}{a_i}=\lambda w_i$ for each $i$.
Substituting in the equations, we get

$x_3=\lambda w_3+ x_1 x_2$
$x_2=\lambda w_2+x_3=\lambda(w_2+w_3)+x_1x_2$
$x_1=\sqrt{\lambda w_1+x_2}$

Substituting the third equation into the second, we get:
$$x_2=\lambda(w_2+w_3)+x_2\sqrt{\lambda w_1+x_2}$$
If $x_2>0$ is a fixed parameter, let us call $f(\lambda)=\lambda(w_2+w_3)+x_2\sqrt{\lambda w_1+x_2}-x_2$. We look for $x_2,\lambda$ such that $f(\lambda)=0$.
Notice that $f(0)=x_2(\sqrt{x_2}-1)$, and $\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty} f(\lambda)=+\infty$. Thus, as soon as $x_2<1$, we have $f(0)<0$, and there is a $\lambda$>0 with $f(\lambda)=0$.
Then we just have to take $x_1=\sqrt{\lambda w_1+x_2}$ and $x_3=\lambda w_3+ x_1x_2$ to obtain the wanted solution.

What am I missing which excludes the simple symmetrical $s_1=x_1-x_2$, $s_2=x_2-x_1$ giving the contradiction $s_2 > s_1 > s_2$?

@PeterTaylor the consistency of inequations is an assumption, I simply don't consider systems where inequations on the $s_i$'s are inconsistent such as this one. I just want to show that if they are consistent at the level of $s_i$'s, then this can be witnessed by some $x_i$'s.

In your three equations for s_i, can we assume that j = j(i) and k = k(i) ? That is, can we assume that the j and k in those equations are each functions of i ?
If not, then I do not understand the question.

@DanielAsimov yes the equation for $s_i$ has specific $j$ and $k$, that we could note $j(i)$ and $k(i)$. This is visible in the example.

I never bother to read past a point that I find to be inadequately explained.
